# How to get index of an item in listview?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a listview that has numbers as its items.

```
ID  |  AT
1      5
2      3
3      7
4      10
5      6
```

Now I want to search an item and get its index. For example I have a textbox and put "4" in it. It will show the index of ID = 4, which should be 3. If I search "1", it should be 0, and so on.

I have tried

```
list = lvNPtable.Items(lvNPtable.Items.IndexOf(textbox1.text))   
Msgbox(list)
```

but doesn't work. Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: `Dim ndx =  myLV.Items.Find(TextBox1.Text, True)`  use false if you dont want to search subitems

Comment: Error, prompt cannot be converted to string when putting ndx in Msgbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Dim intIndex As Integer = lvNPtable.FindItemWithText(TextBox1.Text).Index
```

The `FindItemWithText(String)` method of the `ListView` will return a `ListViewItem`, which you can use the `.Index` property of to get the index value of the item itself, as shown above.

As TimSchmelter pointed out in the comments, there are other parameters you can set when searching, via function overloads:

```
Dim intIndex As Integer = ListView1.FindItemWithText(TextBox1.Text, False, 0, False).Index
```

The first parameter is what you're searching for, second parameter is to search other columns in the list view, third is the starting index to search from, and the fourth is if you are allowing for partial values to return a match.

Comment: It's worth noting that OP should use a different overload like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x03e4732(v=vs.110).aspx). Otherwise also partial matches are allowed or matches in different columns.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good point. I've updated my answer to reflect the overloaded function.